# How do I add the sort extension to an IMAP server?

Tags: java, email-server, imap, web-applications

if we do own a Mail server supporting, how is it possible to add a sort extension to it?

Also how is it possible for a client using java mail to check if the server does indeed support the Sort extension?

For ref: question asked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388208/how-do-i-add-the-sort-extension-to-the-imap-server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the mail server you're using.  It will either be a simple matter of changing a config option, installing a plugin, patching the software, or bugging a commercial vendor to make the necessary changes.

As far as determining whether the server supports it, yes the client should be able to determine whether the server supports the extension by examining the list of capabilities printed when the client connects.  For example, my IMAP server says:

```
* OK [CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 UIDPLUS CHILDREN NAMESPACE THREAD=ORDEREDSUBJECT THREAD=REFERENCES SORT QUOTA IDLE ACL ACL2=UNION]
```

Which indicates that my server already supports sorting.

Comment: this is what i got at mine (copied from debug output):

A0 CAPABILITY
* CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 UNSELECT IDLE NAMESPACE QUOTA XLIST CHILDREN XYZZY

A2 CAPABILITY
* CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 UNSELECT LITERAL+ IDLE NAMESPACE QUOTA ID XLIST CHILDREN X-GM-EXT-1


Making an educated guess: My server does not support sort ?

Comment: Not as-is, by the look of it.  Whether or not you can enable it depends on what sort of IMAP server you're running.

Comment: Its Gmail btw :)

Comment: So it's option the last, "bugging a commercial vendor to make the necessary changes".  Good luck with that.